# Adding json array via JQ introduces unicode characters in string

Tags: json, bash, unicode, jq

I have a JSON file in which I want to append an array element, using bash and latest JQ installed. I am able to append it but the resulting string has unicode characters as can be seen below. The first element in validators array is the original and the second is the appended code. (not the whole json file)

```
"validators": [
{
  "address": "85BAF568E7F89277E47D3FC8E111775A4F6992FA",
  "pub_key": {
    "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
    "value": "BCzCLcW7rZ9VJgAtEUoDN17qcZw8ZvpYbPsL6eOy3No="
  },
  "power": "10",
  "name": ""
},
{
  "address": "\u001b[32m\"F75E15A3949824B685A3C5BFCDEED7E3DA4277AE\"\u001b[0m\r",
  "pub_key": "\u001b[37m{\u001b[0m\u001b[34;1m\"type\"\u001b[0m\u001b[37m:\u001b[0m\u001b[32m\"tendermint/PubKeyEd25519\"\u001b[0m\u001b[37m,\u001b[0m\u001b[34;1m\"value\"\u001b[0m\u001b[37m:\u001b[0m\u001b[32m\"INeR51z41k6jPAEJ5rV+1TY+4sxnbIykc4bfJFmSCQ8=\"\u001b[0m\u001b[37m\u001b[37m}\u001b[0m\r",
  "power": "10",
  "name": "node2"
}
]
```

Printing the address element separately prints the element without any utf/unicode encoding chars.

```
{
    "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
    "value": "BCzCLcW7rZ9VJgAtEUoDN17qcZw8ZvpYbPsL6eOy3No="
}
```

I merge the code using the following code:

```
cat genesis.json.src | jq --arg pub_key $PK --arg name node$i --arg addr $ADDR '.validators+= [{address: $addr, pub_key: $pub_key, power:"10",name:$name}]' > genesis.json.dest
```

I am running macOS. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: The codes look like ANSI colour sequences rather than unicode characters.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right. Never knew about them before. Used "jq -M" option to remove the colour sequences and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @choroba mentioned in the comment, this is colour sequence characters. I removed them by adding a -M flag for JQ that disables colours.